# Cannot access closed file error

Tags: c#, encryption

I get the error "cannot access closed file" when trying to deserialize to XML.
I have a file that is encrypted. I decrypt the file and try to deserialize it when i get this error.
It was working fine without encryption and decryption.

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Models.Test));
var fileLocStream = FileManipultions.DecryptToStream(fileLoc);
var testResult = (Models.Test)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(FileManipultions.DecryptToStream(fileLoc));


 public static Stream DecryptToStream(string inputFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string EncryptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncDesKey"].ToString();
                CryptoStream cs;
                using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

                    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    }
                }
                return cs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogException(ex.Message, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing fsInput (and therefore cs) before the method exits. By the time the caller of the method gets hold of the stream it is closed. Move your code that uses the cs stream inside the `using` for FileStream.

Alternatively, get rid of all the using statements in DecryptToStream() and make your class implement IDisposable so that you can clean up when the done using the Stream.